# Archicad - Create Simple Textbox with Inputs and show saved data

Tags: c++, add-on, archicad, graphisoft

As per a requirement of a job interview, I am tasked with developing add-ons for Archicad with C++. Archicad is totally new to me and I just heard about the software from my interviewer this morning. I visited the ArchiCAD website for their API documentation, but it seems a bit unusual to me. I have never worked with any CAD software like API and Archicad examples are not yet available to me as I've just requested for a Developer ID and it might take 2/3 days to grant me this.

So, I am requesting help with some documentation and proper examples on ***how to build C++ add-ons for ArchiCAD from scratch.***  My task includes :

1. **A windowed add-ons which will have a text box for the name, a drop-down for gender, and a text-box for some descriptions**
2. **A save button to save these data**
3. **And upon saving these data , it will save somewhere inside the persistence database of ArchiCAD add-ons**
4. **The previous saved data will be shown on the windowed add-ons as list box.**

This is all I need to show the recruiter within 3-4 days for qualifying for the next round in the process. So, if anyone comes up with the helping docs or example, I will be truly grateful. *Honestly, I am badly in need of a job.*

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link https://archicadapi.graphisoft.com/getting-started-with-archicad-add-ons. This is a simple tutorial to create an simple Add-ons and add it to the Archicad software.
And again if you installed the API Development Kit for the Archicad. In the installation location you will found a folder called "Examples" where you will get some of the demo project for the add-on. I think that will help you a lot.